# Get video frames information with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, offset

How can I retrieve information from video about byte number from which every frame starts, with using ffmpeg or something else?

Answer (score 28):

You can try `ffprobe`:

```
$ ffprobe -show_frames input.mkv
...
[FRAME]
media_type=video
key_frame=0
pkt_pts=3240
pkt_pts_time=3.240000
pkt_dts=N/A
pkt_dts_time=N/A
best_effort_timestamp=3240
best_effort_timestamp_time=3.240000
pkt_duration=40
pkt_duration_time=0.040000
pkt_pos=18009
pkt_size=480
width=320
height=240
pix_fmt=yuv444p
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=76
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
[/FRAME]
```

- `pkt_pos` may be what you're looking for.
- If you only want info from the video stream add `-select_streams v:0`.
- See [FFprobe Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) and [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for more examples.

Comment: `-select_streams v:0` will filter to the first video stream in the stream.  To filter so all video streams (if there are more than 1) are returned use `-select_streams v`