# display only lines from output that contains a specified word

Tags: linux, bash, ffprobe, grip

I'm looking for a way to get only the lines that contains a specified word, in this case all lines that contains the word *Stream* from an output

I've tried;

```
streams=$(ffprobe -i  "movie.mp4"  | grep "Stream")
```

but that didn't get any results..

or do I need to output it to a file and then try to extract the lines I'm looking for?

Comment: "grep" should be what you're looking for.  Q: What does `ffprobe -i  "movie.mp4"  | grep "Stream"` look like when you run it from the command line?  Perhaps "ffprobe" isn't writing to stdout?  Or "Stream" is spelled differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@paulsm4 was spot on ... the output goes to STDERR.

```
streams=$(ffprobe -i  "movie.mp4"  |& grep "Stream")
```

Note the **&**

Comment: Yes @JoBe ... unix/linux tools typically implement both standard output and standard error as separate streams, in short STDOUT/STDERR  ... for some reason the developer of `ffprobe` seems to think of their output as "error" rather than "output", the reason for this I can't quite fathom.

Comment: The ffmpeg tools have a common logging API. Since ffmpeg can pipe media data over stdout, logs are sent to stderr.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `grep`. Just use `ffprobe` directly to get whatever info you need.

## Output all info

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_format -show_streams input.mp4
```

## Video info only

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams -select_streams v input.mp4
```

## Audio info only

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams -select_streams a input.mp4
```

## Width x height

See [Getting video dimension / resolution / width x height from ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29585066/)

## Duration

See [How to get video duration?](https://superuser.com/a/945604/)

## Format / codec

- [Is there a way to use ffmpeg to determine the encoding of a file before transcoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280871/)
- [Using ffprobe to check audio-only files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289198/)

## Info on frames

See [Get video frames information with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27531667/)

## More info and examples

See [FFmpeg Wiki: ffprobe](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips)